# foreach loop in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, foreach

I was going through the `forEach` `loop` in `AngularJS`. There are few points that I did not understood about it.

1. What is the use of the iterator function? Is there any way to go without it?
2. What is the significance of the key and value as shown below?

`angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key){});`

**PS:** I tried to run this function without the arguments and it did not work.

Here's my `json`:

```
[
   {
     "Name": "Thomas",
     "Password": "thomasTheKing"
   },
   {
     "Name": "Linda",
     "Password": "lindatheQueen"
   }
]
```

My `JavaScript` file:

```
var app = angular.module('testModule', []);

app.controller('testController', function($scope, $http){
   $http.get('Data/info.json').then(
      function(data){
         $scope.data = data;
      }
   );

   angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key){
      if(value.Password == "thomasTheKing")
         console.log("username is thomas");
   });
});
```

**Another question**: Why the function above does not enter on if condition and print "username is thomas" in the console?

Comment: Because you're not waiting for the `success` to happen of your `$http.get()`, thus, when `angular.forEach()` happens, `$scope.data` is still undefined.

Comment: Is there any specific way to hold the execution of the code untill the json is loaded

Comment: Change the line into this

 angular.forEach(values, function(value, key){
   console.log(key + ': ' + value.Name);
 });

Answer (score 212, accepted):

### Questions 1 & 2

So basically, first parameter is the object to iterate on. It can be an array or an object. If it is an object like this :

```
var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
```

Angular will take each value one by one the first one is name, the second is gender.

If your object to iterate on is an array (also possible), like this :

```
[{ "Name" : "Thomas", "Password" : "thomasTheKing" },
 { "Name" : "Linda", "Password" : "lindatheQueen" }]
```

Angular.forEach will take one by one starting by the first object, then the second object.

For each of this object, it will so take them one by one and execute a specific code for each value. This code is called **the iterator function**. forEach is smart and behave differently if you are using an array of a collection. Here is some exemple :

```
var obj = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
var log = [];
angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
  console.log(key + ': ' + value);
});
// it will log two iteration like this
// name: misko
// gender: male
```

So key is the string value of your key and value is ... the value. You can use the key to access your value like this : `obj['name'] = 'John'`

If this time you display an array, like this :

```
var values = [{ "Name" : "Thomas", "Password" : "thomasTheKing" },
           { "Name" : "Linda", "Password" : "lindatheQueen" }];
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key){
     console.log(key + ': ' + value);
});
// it will log two iteration like this
// 0: [object Object]
// 1: [object Object]
```

So then value is your object (collection), and key is the index of your array since :

```
[{ "Name" : "Thomas", "Password" : "thomasTheKing" },
 { "Name" : "Linda", "Password" : "lindatheQueen" }]
// is equal to
{0: { "Name" : "Thomas", "Password" : "thomasTheKing" },
 1: { "Name" : "Linda", "Password" : "lindatheQueen" }}
```

I hope it answer your question. Here is a JSFiddle to run some code and test if you want : http://jsfiddle.net/ygahqdge/

### Debugging your code

The problem seems to come from the fact `$http.get()` is an asynchronous request.

You send a query on your son, **THEN** when you browser end downloading it it execute success. **BUT** just after sending your request your perform a loop using `angular.forEach` without waiting the answer of your JSON.

You need to include the loop in the success function

```
var app = angular.module('testModule', [])
    .controller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('Data/info.json').then(function(data){
         $scope.data = data;

         angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key){
         if(value.Password == "thomasTheKing")
           console.log("username is thomas");
         });
    });

});
```

This should work.

### Going more deeply

> The [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#!) API is based on the [deferred/promise APIs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) exposed by the $q
>   service. While for simple usage patterns this doesn't matter much, for
>   advanced usage it is important to familiarize yourself with these APIs
>   and the guarantees they provide.

You can give a look at [deferred/promise APIs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), it is an important concept of Angular to make smooth asynchronous actions.

Comment: Colin B (profile [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3177901/colin-b) . ) wanted to comment that `success` and `error` [have been deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice). Using `then` method instead of `success` is suggested. Now, @Colin, go out and Answer a few questions to get 50 rep !  :P

Comment: Async is not parallel. For parallel, he'll need webworkers, not promises. Tiny bit pedantic, but worth stopping misinformation on that whenever it happens.

Comment: Thanks @KyleBaker, I updated this answer, you're right "parallel" was an abuse of language.

Comment: @sebastienbarbier  can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100381/while-looping-api-response-in-accordion-menu-data-missing-in-angular4

Answer (score 7):

you have to use nested angular.forEach loops for JSON as shown below:

```
 var values = [
        {
            "name":"Thomas",
            "password":"thomas"
        },
        { 
            "name":"linda",
            "password":"linda"
        }];

    angular.forEach(values,function(value,key){
        angular.forEach(value,function(v1,k1){//this is nested angular.forEach loop
            console.log(k1+":"+v1);
        });
    });
```

Comment: No, you would use a single loop, and frankly, in this case, you should just use the native forEach(), a la `values.forEach(object => console.log(`${object.name}: ${object.password}`))`.

Comment: Just change the line console.log(key + ': ' + value);
INTO console.log(key + ': ' + value.Name);

Answer (score 5):

The `angular.forEach()` will iterate through your `json` object.

First iteration,

> key = 0, value = { "name" : "Thomas", "password" : "thomasTheKing"}

Second iteration,

> key = 1, value = { "name" : "Linda", "password" : "lindatheQueen" }

To get the value of your `name`, you can use `value.name` or `value["name"]`. Same with your `password`, you use `value.password` or `value["password"]`.

**The code below will give you what you want:**

```
   angular.forEach(json, function (value, key)
         {
                //console.log(key);
                //console.log(value);
                if (value.password == "thomasTheKing") {
                    console.log("username is thomas");
                }
         });
```

Answer (score 3):

In Angular 7 the for loop is like below

```
var values = [
        {
            "name":"Thomas",
            "password":"thomas"
        },
        { 
            "name":"linda",
            "password":"linda"
        }];

for (let item of values)
{
}
```

Comment: Angular version 2.x  or later is completely different than angularjs [< 2 ], they've even named differently.  Even though plain JS is always there, Angularjs and Angular are completely different in terms of many things.

Answer (score 2):

Change the line into this

```
 angular.forEach(values, function(value, key){
   console.log(key + ': ' + value);
 });

 angular.forEach(values, function(value, key){
   console.log(key + ': ' + value.Name);
 });
```