# Can not get any value using for each loop of angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem in angular.js foreach loop.I have a console message `console.log('course data',response.data);` whose output given below.

```
course data [Object, Object, Object]
0: Objectcourse_name: "Master of computer 
1: Objectcourse_name: "Bachelor of Technology"
2: Objectcourse_name: "Master in Technology"
length: 3__proto__: Array[0]
```

i have some code for angular foreach loop which is given below.

```
angular.forEach(response.data, function(value, key){
       console.log(key + ': ' + value);
     });
```

but here i am getting the following output of the console message given inside the code.

```
0: [object Object]
1: [object Object]
2: [object Object]
```

I am not getting the key name as well as value.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
angular.forEach(response.data, function(obj){
   console.log(obj.name + ': ' + obj.value);  });
```

Here name and value will be the key of your Object contains..

Answer (score 0):

I think your data is an array of objects. Try:

```
angular.forEach(response.data, function(index, item){
   console.log(index + ': ' + item.Objectcourse_name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself also the answer.i tried the below code and got the output.

```
angular.forEach(response.data, function(value){
       console.log(value.course_name)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code absolutely fine, but the problem is with your array data. " is missing against Master of Computer. I have describe you another example below.

```
course data [Object, Object, Object]
0: Objectcourse_name: "Master of computer" 
1: Objectcourse_name: "Bachelor of Technology"
2: Objectcourse_name: "Master in Technology"
length: 3__proto__: Array[0]
```

angular.forEach

> Invokes the iterator function once for each item in obj collection,
>   which can be either an object or an array.

```
var obj = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
var log = [];
angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
  console.log(key + ': ' + value);
});
// it will log two iteration like this
// name: misko
// gender: male
```

See complete documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

Need any clarifications, please see its [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953198/foreach-loop-in-angularjs)

Answer (score -1):

You are concatenating strings, not printing an object.
Try this:

```
console.log(key, value)
```