# JavaScript (Angular) ForEach Loop Changes Not Applying

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects with a date formatted in `MMMM Do YYYY` format. I need to convert this into a UNIX timestamp to arrange them and then convert them back into the readable date format.

However, in doing this. It seems that my changes from within the `forEach` callback are not applied to the `$scope.lalala` variable.

My code:

```
    function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.date < b.date)
    return -1;
  if (a.date > b.date)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
$scope.lalala = arrayofincompleteorders;
$scope.lalala.forEach(function(hiVanilla, index) {
  hiVanilla.date = moment(hiVanilla.date, 'MMMM Do YYYY').format('x');
  if (index == $scope.lalala.length - 1) {
    $scope.lalala.sort(compare); timestamps as expected
    console.log($scope.lalala); //logs the date property with unix 
    callback();
  }
});
console.log($scope.lalala); //logs the date property with unix timestamps, why?

function callback() {
  $scope.lalala.forEach(function(order, index) {
    console.log(order.date); //unix timestamp
    $scope.lalala[index].date = moment(order.date, 'x').format('MMMM Do YYYY');
    console.log($scope.lalala[index].date); //formatted timestamp
  });
};
```

Edit: I have the same problem even with the angular.forEach loop in the callback:

```
function callback(){
    angular.forEach($scope.lalala, function(value, key) {
    console.log(value.date);
  value.date = moment(value.date, 'x').format('MMMM Do YYYY');
  console.log($scope.lalala[key].date);
});
  console.log("fire!");
  $scope.apply();
};
```

I get the dates to change successfully but then it says that `$scope.apply()` is not a function which borks the rest of my script.

Edit2:

I got rid of the callback and have everything in one `angular.forEach` but it still doesn't apply?

```
$scope.lalala = arrayofincompleteorders;
 angular.forEach($scope.lalala, function(hiVanilla, key) {
  hiVanilla.date = moment(hiVanilla.date, 'MMMM Do YYYY').format('x');
  if (key == $scope.lalala.length - 1) {
    $scope.lalala.sort(compare); //timestamps as expected
    console.log($scope.lalala); //logs the date property with unix 
    console.log(hiVanilla.date); //unix timestamp
    hiVanilla.date = moment(hiVanilla.date, 'x').format('MMMM Do YYYY');
    console.log($scope.lalala[key].date); //formatted timestamp
  }
});
console.log($scope.lalala); //logs the date property with unix timestamps, why?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [foreach loop in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953198/foreach-loop-in-angularjs)

Comment: @AhmadBamieh that looks like a different (angular specific) function... is that what I should be using?

Comment: yes, you need to update the scope to reflect the changes, you can do this manually by calling `$scope.apply` or using angular helpers such as angular.foreach

Comment: @AhmadBamieh I get $scope.apply() is not a function and it seems necessary even when using the angular `forEach`

Comment: @AhmadBamieh when I change to $scope.$apply() I get a digest already in progress error! :(

Comment: can you put your code in a jsfiddle? i'll fix it for you

Comment: @AhmadBamieh https://jsfiddle.net/t42v05p7/

Comment: @AhmadBamieh I tried a `$timeout` to deal with the issue with `apply()` btw

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was using `angular.forEach` in a way that it was not designed.

The following worked, basically I just assigned it by pushing it into an empty array rather than trying to alter the array from which I was looping inside of:

```
        $scope.lalala=[];
        var log = = arrayofincompleteorders;
        angular.forEach(log, function(value, key) {
        if(value.complete!="TRUE")
        {
        i++;
        value.date = moment(value.date, 'x').format('MMMM Do YYYY');
        this.push(value); //put the new value in $scope.lalala as specified below
        }
        }, $scope.lalala);
```