# Angular forEach not iterating

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to iterate through a list of objects in my lovely Angular/Typescript code, but for some reason it doesn't even attempt to do so.  Here's the code:

```
businessList: RemoteDataSet<BusinessModel>;
businessModel: BusinessModel; 

this.businessList.forEach( bl => {
            console.log("in foreach");
            if (bl.id == this.user.businessId) {
                console.log("they are equal");
                this.businessModel = bl;
            }
            else {
                console.log("They are not equal");
            }
        });
```

I've verified that this.businessList has data (about 40 items).  Even so, it doesn't iterate through even once.  I'm obviously pretty new to Angular and Typescript, but this seems right.  What am I missing?

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. In particular,  post the code of RemoteDataSet and its forEach() method. We can't possibly guess how it's implemented.

Comment: If you could also post a sample of your JSON `BusinessModel` objects it would be very helpful.

Comment: You incorrectly invoked the angular foreach loop.
angular.forEach(businessList =>{...}  
is what it should be.
Check this previous question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953198/foreach-loop-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try the `angular.forEach` method?

```
    forEachFunction = () => {
        angular.forEach(this.businessList, (value, key) => {
            if (value.id == this.user.businessId) {
                console.log("they are equal");
                this.businessModel = value;
            }
            else {
                console.log("They are not equal");
            }
        });
    };
```